# Heatmapped png's not being created on disk

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

I'm creating a heatmap for a CNN as per [this](https://www.ahmedbesbes.com/blog/acl-tear-detection-part-3) tutorial.

In the last part:

```
def create_patiens_cam(case, plane):
    patient_id = case['id']
    mri = case['mri']

    folder_path = f'./CAMS/{plane}/{patient_id}/'
    if os.path.isdir(folder_path):
        shutil.rmtree(folder_path)
    os.makedirs(folder_path)
    os.makedirs(folder_path + 'slices/')
    os.makedirs(folder_path + 'cams/')
    
    params = list(mrnet.parameters())
    weight_softmax = np.squeeze(params[-2].cpu().data.numpy())
    
    num_slices = mri.shape[1]
    global feature_blobs
    feature_blobs = []
    mri = mri.to(device)
    logit = mrnet(mri)
    size_upsample = (256, 256)
    feature_conv = feature_blobs[0]
    
    h_x = F.softmax(logit, dim=1).data.squeeze(0)
    probs, idx = h_x.sort(0, True)
    probs = probs.cpu().numpy()
    idx = idx.cpu().numpy()
    slice_cams = returnCAM(feature_blobs[-1], weight_softmax, idx[:1])
    
    for s in tqdm_notebook(range(num_slices), leave=False):
        slice_pil = (transforms
                     .ToPILImage()(mri.cpu()[0][s] / 255))
        slice_pil.save(folder_path + f'slices/{s}.png', 
                       dpi=(300, 300))
         
        img = mri[0][s].cpu().numpy()
        img = img.transpose(1, 2, 0)
        heatmap = (cv2
                    .cvtColor(cv2.applyColorMap(
                        cv2.resize(slice_cams[s], (256, 256)),
                        cv2.COLORMAP_JET), 
                               cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                  )
        result = heatmap * 0.3 + img * 0.5  
        
        pil_img_cam = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(result))
        pil_img_cam.save(folder_path + f'cams/{s}.png', dpi=(300, 300))
```

I have created a folder "CAMS" in my 'mrnet' folder. However when running this last code (in jupyter notebook) I get no errors but no png's are being created. Anyone has any idea what could be wrong or where I could look to see what's wrong as I get no errors?

FULL CODE:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Mar 13 21:54:40 2021

@author: GlaDOS
"""

import os
import io
import requests
from PIL import Image
from torchvision import models, transforms
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torch.nn import functional as F
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pdb

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import sys
sys.path.append('C:/Users/GlaDOS/mrnet')

import shutil
import torch
import model
from dataloader import MRDataset
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook

task = 'acl'
plane = 'sagittal'
prefix = 'sag'

model_name = [name  for name in os.listdir('C:/Users/GlaDOS/mrnet/models/') 
              if (task in name) and 
                 (plane in name) and 
                 (prefix in name)][0]

is_cuda = torch.cuda.is_available()
device = torch.device("cuda" if is_cuda else "cpu")

mrnet = torch.load(f'C:/Users/GlaDOS/mrnet/models/{model_name}')
mrnet = mrnet.to(device)

_ = mrnet.eval()

dataset = MRDataset('C:/Users/GlaDOS/mrnet/data/', 
                    task, 
                    plane, 
                    transform=None, 
                    train=False)
loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, 
                                     batch_size=1, 
                                     shuffle=False, 
                                     num_workers=0, 
                                     drop_last=False)

def returnCAM(feature_conv, weight_softmax, class_idx):
    size_upsample = (256, 256)
    bz, nc, h, w = feature_conv.shape
    slice_cams = []
    for s in range(bz):
        for idx in class_idx:
            cam = weight_softmax[idx].dot(feature_conv[s].reshape((nc, h*w)))
            cam = cam.reshape(h, w)
            cam = cam - np.min(cam)
            cam_img = cam / np.max(cam)
            cam_img = np.uint8(255 * cam_img)
            slice_cams.append(cv2.resize(cam_img, size_upsample))
    return slice_cams


patients = []

for i, (image, label, _) in tqdm_notebook(enumerate(loader), total=len(loader)):
    patient_data = {}
    patient_data['mri'] = image
    patient_data['label'] = label[0][0][1].item()
    patient_data['id'] = '0' * (4 - len(str(i))) + str(i)
    patients.append(patient_data)

acl = list(filter(lambda d: d['label'] == 1, patients))



def create_patiens_cam(case, plane):
    patient_id = case['id']
    mri = case['mri']

    folder_path = f'C:/Users/GlaDOS/mrnet/cams/{plane}/{patient_id}/'
    if os.path.isdir(folder_path):
        shutil.rmtree(folder_path)
    os.makedirs(folder_path)
    os.makedirs(folder_path + 'slices/')
    os.makedirs(folder_path + 'cams/')
    
    params = list(mrnet.parameters())
    weight_softmax = np.squeeze(params[-2].cpu().data.numpy())
    
    num_slices = mri.shape[1]
    global feature_blobs
    feature_blobs = []
    mri = mri.to(device)
    logit = mrnet(mri)
    size_upsample = (256, 256)
    feature_conv = feature_blobs[0]
    
    h_x = F.softmax(logit, dim=1).data.squeeze(0)
    probs, idx = h_x.sort(0, True)
    probs = probs.cpu().numpy()
    idx = idx.cpu().numpy()
    slice_cams = returnCAM(feature_blobs[-1], weight_softmax, idx[:1])
    
    for s in tqdm_notebook(range(num_slices), leave=False):
        slice_pil = (transforms
                     .ToPILImage()(mri.cpu()[0][s] / 255))
        slice_pil.save(folder_path + f'slices/{s}.png', 
                       dpi=(300, 300))
         
        img = mri[0][s].cpu().numpy()
        img = img.transpose(1, 2, 0)
        heatmap = (cv2
                    .cvtColor(cv2.applyColorMap(
                        cv2.resize(slice_cams[s], (256, 256)),
                        cv2.COLORMAP_JET), 
                               cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                  )
        result = heatmap * 0.3 + img * 0.5  
        
        pil_img_cam = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(result))
        pil_img_cam.save(folder_path + f'cams/{s}.png', dpi=(300, 300))
```

Comment: please create a folder named "cams" use lower cases and then run again

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: I've updated with my full code which returns no errors, nor in jupyter nor spyder.

Comment: Does "slice_pil.save(folder_path + f'slices/{s}.png', dpi=(300, 300))" work perfectly?

Comment: It's not even creating the CAMS folder. It should, shouldn't it? As it says   folder_path = f'./CAMS/{plane}/{patient_id}/'
    if os.path.isdir(folder_path):
        shutil.rmtree(folder_path)
    os.makedirs(folder_path)

Comment: I've tried deleting the cams folder and it does not create one.

Comment: folder_path = f'C:/Users/GlaDOS/mrnet/cams/{plane}/{patient_id}/' change this to folder_path = f'C:/Users/GlaDOS/mrnet/CAMS/{plane}/{patient_id}/'

Comment: Nope, nothing seems to work. I'm surprised I get no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use seaborn:

> import seaborn as sns
> sns_plot.savefig('output.png')

Comment: It is about saving the image in the specific folder path. Your answer don't meet the cause

Comment: These are several slices of an MRI so multiple pictures. That's why it creates several png's (or should).